# Regex noob question: getting several words/sentences from one line, max separation being 1 whitespace?

Tags: python, regex

I'm not terribly familiar with Python regex, or regex in general, but I'm hoping to demystify it all a bit more with time.

My problem is this: given a string like `'     Apple     Banana     Cucumber    Alphabetical Fruit   Whoops'`, I'm trying to use python's 're.findall' module to result in a list that looks like this: `my_list = ['     Apple', '     Banana', '     Cucumber', '    Alphabetical Fruit', '   Whoops']`. In other words, I'm trying to find a regex expression that can [look for a bunch of whitespace followed by some non-whitespace], and then check if there is a single space with some more non-whitespace characters after that.

This is the function I've written that gets me *cloooose* but not quite:

`re.findall("\s+\S+\s{1}\S*", my_list)`

Which results in:

`['     Apple ', '    Banana ', '    Cucumber ', '   Alphabetical Fruit']`

I think this result makes sense. It first finds the whitespace, then some non-whitespace, but then it looks for at least one whitespace (which leaves out 'Whoops'), and then looks for any number of other non-whitespace characters (which is why there's no space after 'Alphabetical Fruit'). I just don't know what character combination would give me the intended result.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!
-WW

Comment: `re.findall` isn't a module. `re` is a module and `re.findall` is a function from the `re` module.

Comment: Good note. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
\s+\w+(?:\s\w+)?
```

- `\s+\w+` macthes one or more whitespaces, followed by one or more of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- `(?:\s\w+)?` is a conditional (`?`, zero or one) non-captured group (`(?:)`) that matches a whitespace (`\s`) followed by one or more of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (`\w+`). Essentially this is to match `Fruit` in `Alphabetical Fruit`.

**Example:**

```
In [701]: text = '     Apple     Banana     Cucumber    Alphabetical Fruit   Whoops'                                                                                                                        

In [702]: re.findall(r'\s+\w+(?:\s\w+)?', text)                                                                                                                                                             
Out[702]: 
['     Apple',
 '     Banana',
 '     Cucumber',
 '    Alphabetical Fruit',
 '   Whoops']
```

Comment: You are absolutely amazing. Thank you so much, this is perfect. <3 Also, Regex makes yet more sense to me!

Comment: @Werewoof Glad, I could help :)

Comment: Whoops, forgot. Checked!

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern works already, just make the second part (the 'compound word' part) optional:

`\s+\S+(\s\S+)?`

https://regex101.com/r/Ua8353/3/

(fixed `\s{1}` per @heemayl)

Comment: No need for `{1}`, single `\s` means `\s{1}`.